# weak closedness of a set with bounded functions

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $A$ be a compact topological space equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and $X=B_b(A)$ be the vector space of bounded   measurable functions. Let $Y=\mathcal M(A)$ be the vector space of finite signed measure on $A$. Define the dual pair $<\cdot, \cdot>$ between $(X,Y)$ such that $
<f, \mu >=\int_A f(a)\mu(da)
$.
Let $\sigma(X,Y)$ be the weakest topology such that for all $\mu\in Y$, the linear map $X\ni f\mapsto <f,\mu>\in \mathbb R$ is continuous.

Define the set $U=\{f\in X\mid \sup_{a\in A}|f(a)|\ge 1\}$. Is the set $U$ closed in the $\sigma(X,Y)$ topology?
I am not sure how to proceed to prove or disprove the claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, assuming $A$ is $T_1$ and infinite. Indeed, just choose a sequence of distinct points $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset A$. Then $f_n = 1_{\{a_n\}} \in U$, but $f_n \to 0$ pointwise, so as they are uniformly bounded by $1$, by bounded convergence theorem, $\langle f_n, \mu \rangle \to 0$ for all $\mu \in Y$, i.e., $f_n \to 0$ in $\sigma(X, Y)$ topology. But $0 \notin U$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo and the answer.

Comment: Is $f_n \rightarrow 0$ pointwise is enough ? Shouldnt the convergence be in something like sup norm. Although for the given set of functions it seems to work.

Comment: @Balajisb https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Bounded_convergence_theorem

Comment: I agree then its better to mention your functions are uniformly bounded also. Because in the space of bounded functions, pointwise convergence in general does not imply dominated convergence theorem i think. Just for book keeping. I am not saying much.

Comment: @Balajisb I mean, when I was writing the answer I was under the impression that that was obvious, but sure, if you think that will make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks. Does the fact that measure here is "signed" create any nuances ?

Comment: @Balajisb No. $|\int f \, d\mu| \leq \int |f| \, d|\mu|$. If $\mu$ is a finite signed measure, then $|\mu|$ is a finite positive measure, so you can just apply bounded convergence to $|\mu|$ and obtain the version for signed measures as a corollary.